# Accordion Menu in home page

Tags: ionic3, angular4-httpclient

[Create New Ionic 3 and Angular 4 Accordion Menu App](https://www.djamware.com/post/58fdf9f080aca7414e78a63a/ionic-3-and-angular-4-multi-level-accordion-menu-example?fbclid=IwAR2hmF9B_tbaHw8LxoVS3zNkGgH0aws3WMl43hz_Elw6NpVoW9to4TSRPM0)

I really wanted to view this Accordion Menu in my home page for my project i tried to edit this code so many time but i wasn't able to did it right. I hope you guys takes time to help me with this. thank you for your future answers.

here it is:
**Create Nested Array of Objects**

> We have to create nested Array of objects which it's contains
>   multilevel arrays. Create a new folder and JSON file in the asset
>   folder.

mkdir src/assets/data

touch src/assets/data/menus.json

> Open and edit 'menus.json' then add this lines of data.

```
[
  {
    "category":"PC",
    "subs": [
      {
        "subcategory":"Processor",
        "manufactures": [
          {
            "manufacture":"Intel"
          },
          {
            "manufacture":"AMD"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "subcategory":"Motherboard",
        "manufactures": [
          {
            "manufacture":"Asus"
          },
          {
            "manufacture":"AMD"
          },
          {
            "manufacture":"GigaByte"
          },
          {
            "manufacture":"Intel"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "subcategory":"Memory",
        "manufactures": [
          {
            "manufacture":"Visipro"
          },
          {
            "manufacture":"Crucial"
          },
          {
            "manufacture":"VenomRX"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category":"Laptop",
    "subs": [
      {
        "subcategory":"Notebook",
        "manufactures": [
          {
            "manufacture":"Lenovo"
          },
          {
            "manufacture":"Dell"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "subcategory":"Netbook",
        "manufactures": [
          {
            "manufacture":"Lenovo"
          },
          {
            "manufacture":"Dell"
          },
          {
            "manufacture":"Acer"
          },
          {
            "manufacture":"HP"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category":"Printer",
    "subs": [
      {
        "subcategory":"Laserjet",
        "manufactures": [
          {
            "manufacture":"HP"
          },
          {
            "manufacture":"Brother"
          },
          {
            "manufacture":"Canon"
          },
          {
            "manufacture":"Samsung"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "subcategory":"Deskjet",
        "manufactures": [
          {
            "manufacture":"HP"
          },
          {
            "manufacture":"Canon"
          },
          {
            "manufacture":"Epson"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Create and Call Service/Provider for Accessing Data**

> To access JSON data we have to create new service or provider to keep
>   app modular. Type this command to create it.

ionic g provider DataService

> Open and edit 'src/providers/data-service.ts' add 'Response' to 'Http'
>   import.

```
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
```

Create this function for call JSON data.

```
getMenus(){
  return this.http.get('assets/data/menus.json')
   .map((response:Response)=>response.json());
}
```

> Register this service in 'app.module.ts' by open and edit
>   'src/app/app.module.ts' then add this import.

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { DataService } from '../providers/data-service';
```

> Add 'HttpModule' in '@NgModule' imports.

```
...
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
],
...
```

> Add 'DataService' in '@NgModule' providers.

```
...
providers: [
  StatusBar,
  SplashScreen,
  {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
  DataService
]
...
```

> Because menu holds by component, we have to edit it to call data for
>   the menu from service/provider. Open and edit
>   'src/app/app.component.ts' then add this import.

```
import { DataService } from '../providers/data-service';
```

> Replace this line.

```
pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;
```

> With this.

```
pages: any;
```

> Now, inject 'DataService' in constructor parameter and add this
>   function for calling JSON data inside of the constructor.

```
constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public 
splashScreen: SplashScreen, public dataService: DataService) {
  this.initializeApp();

  this.dataService.getMenus()
    .subscribe((response)=> {
        this.pages = response;
        console.log(this.pages);
    });

}
```

> Create Multilevel Accordion Menu Now, is the point. Creating
>   multilevel Accordion Menu with Ionic 3 and Angular 4. Open and edit
>   'src/app/app.html' the add this lines of codes inside ''.

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" text-wrap>
      {{p.category}}
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let s of p.subs" text-wrap>
          {{s.subcategory}}
          <ion-list>
            <ion-item *ngFor="let m of s.manufactures" text-wrap>
              {{m.manufacture}}
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

> After we re-run the Ionic 3 app, the menu should look like this.

[image: Side Menu]

> I wanted it in my HomePage.

[image: Home Menu]

thank you for your future answers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are still looking for the answer. If yes, then I have created a plugin for Angular which creates a Multilevel menu. Now you can convert this multilevel menu to Accordion as well, for example, Check [this example](https://multilevel-menu-demo.web.app/pages/layout-variations/demo-three).

Here is a [NPM Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-material-multilevel-menu) and [Github Link](https://github.com/ShankyTiwari/ng-material-multilevel-menu), the documentation is very sweet and simple.

Just in case, if you wanna see more examples, I have a [demo](https://multilevel-menu-demo.web.app/) for you and this is the [Github Repo](https://github.com/ShankyTiwari/ng-material-multilevel-menu-demo) of the demo.

If something doesn't work for you, and you still wanna use this plugin, then [create an issue](https://github.com/ShankyTiwari/ng-material-multilevel-menu/issues) here I'll help you out.

P.S. it works in IE11 as well.

Thanks